# Mongoose & MongoDB: Retrieve results narrowed by multiple parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to get data from MongoDB that is first narrowed by one initial category, say '{clothing : pants}' and then a subsequent search for pants of a specific size, using an array like sizes = ['s','lg','6', '12'].

I need to return all of the results where 'pants' matches those 'sizes'.

I've started a search with:

```
    Product.find({$and:[{categories:req.body.category, size:{$in:req.body.sizes}}]},
    function(err, products) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        return res.send(products)
    });
```

I really don't know where to go from there.  I've been all over the Mongoose docs.

Some direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose queries can receive object like Mongodb would. So you can pass the search parameters separated by `,`

```
Product.find({categories:req.body.category, size:{$in:['s','lg','6', '12']}})
```

For more information on $in, check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

For more information on $and operator, check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) (note we can ommit the $and operator in some cases and that is what I did)